# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / fix problem sudo apt update / is configuring multiple times

Tags: command-line, 20.04, updates, sudo

when I enter the line: sudo apt update, the Terminal shows me: (...) is configured multiple times...

It is the first time I am using this operating system. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks you.

```
All packages are up-to-date.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:62 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:62 and /etc/apt/sources.list:64
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:63
```

Comment: Please don't use capital letters in the title. Looks like shouting.

Comment: Hi pLumo, as you said, it is just a title. I always use it for that purpose. My question was closed. I have a problem. I use this function: "Download the PYZ bundle (aptsources-cleanup.pyz)". It did not work. Could you help me?